# Whats the difference between these two practices:

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am new to multi-threading, I am following a book written by Albahari Joe and watching a course on Pluralsight, but I get stuck quite often when I want to know more about threads and how to properly, safely and efficiently use them. I have searched here for a solution but couldn't find one. So please don't irritate with my basic questions! Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
new Thread(Work).Start();     
OR
Thread t = new Thread(WriteB); t.Start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference is that with the second line, you can still access the new `Thread` instance via the variable `t`.

For instance, if you would like to wait for the thread to finish, you'd use:

```
Thread t = new Thread(WriteB); 
t.Start();
// ... do work while the other thread also does work ...
t.Join();
```

You wouldn't be able to do that without assigning the `Thread` to a variable.

Comment: c# looks so much like Java:) with the exception of Capitalise in the method name.

Comment: Thanks to considering, but my bad I don't get it fully.

Comment: What you meant by this
// `... do work while the other thread also does work ...`
Could I make new threads and calling them or can do something with main thread?

Comment: You can do whatever you want there. The idea is that you can still access the `Thread` instance _after_ you've started it, while if you use `new Thread(...).Start()` you will not be able to access it anymore. All this code you see here will run on the "main" thread, while the `WriteB` method will run on the newly created thread.

Comment: Yeah thanks, well explained. And that work method in the first snippet will also run in another thread.